# Value does not exist

Tags: elasticsearch

I am familiar with checking if a field exists using the exists query. I am wondering if there is a way to check if a value does not exist instead; something like this:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "user",
           "value": "id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:**

I want to add that it is a compound query so counting the result will not work.

Comment: Not that I’m aware of. Could you maybe just check if it returns an error when you query it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that if a particular field value exists or not, then you can simply use a [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html). There is no need to use exists query with the `must_not` clause.

If the document matching the field value is there in your index, then its count will come in the search result. **`hits.total.value` will you the count of matching documents.**

Adding a working example

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "user": "abc"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size":0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "user": "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,              // note this
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
```

---

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size":0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "user": "def"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 0,                // note this
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
```

---

Another option is to use count API

```
GET /_count
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "user": "def"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
{
  "count": 0,           // note this
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: @kehers did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)